# XSD child elements optional/required based on the parent attribute name

Tags: xml, xsd

I am working on a XSD validation code and I am trying to figure out how to validate a XML file that has

```
<root>
    <elementA attribute1=ID>
    ...
    </elementA>
    <elementA attribute2=ID>
    ...
    </elementA>
</root>
```

and I want to make the XSD where it validates the same element based off the attribute name and makes some of the child element optional for `attribute1` while required for `attribute2`.

Note that "..." is the same elements with some fields being optional for `attribute1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSD 1.0 the type of an element can depend only on the element name, and not on its attributes. XSD 1.1 removes this restriction with a facility called "conditional type assignment". XSD 1.1 is currently implemented only in Xerces and Saxon.